# jQuery + Lightbox: Как заставить работать оба скрипта?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, lightbox

Добрый день.

Я использую jQuery для анимации кнопок, и lightbox для отображения выделенных картинок.

[image]

Но работает только что-то одно, в данном случае lightbox. Код:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.5.1.min.js"></script> 
<script src="js/prototype.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/scriptaculous.js?load=effects,builder" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/lightbox.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/lightbox.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
```

Применяю к картинке так:

```
<a href="blg.jpg" rel="lightbox" title="News Blog" target="_blank";/>
<img src="http://my.jetscreenshot.com/10682/20120401-qcva-4kb.jpg" style="width:50px; height:50px;"/></a>
```

Если оставить только:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.5.1.min.js"></script>
```

Тогда работает только jQuery.

**Как заставить работать оба скрипта?**

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.5.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">jQuery.noConflict();</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/prototype.js"></script>
```

ЗЫ Кстати почему jquery 1.5.1? Пора на 1.7 переползать...

Comment: да, ну после этого. все обращения к $ надо будет поменять на jQuery.
см http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

Comment: А смысл переползать на 1.7 и т.д. оно больше раз в 5 чем допустим 1.2 или 1.3, потому как куча не нужных функций, мне например, 1.2.6 за глаза хватает, чтоб например что-то заанимировать)

Comment: Поправил свои две строчки, на три ваших.
Работает только лайтбокс, кнопки не реагируют..
Может быть проблемой версия библиотеки?

Comment: обращение $ поменяли на jQuery?

Comment: @armenka ну так можно и на pure js сидеть...

Comment: вы советовали менять на $ в случае перехода на 1.7. Или в моем случае, тоже надо поменять? Вот функция. Я правильно выделил все $ что нужно заменить? http://4url.ru/11980

Comment: Да, везде надо поменять. Просто jQuery и prototype обе используют псевдоним $. Соответственно jQuery.noConflict() освобождает $ для использования другими библиотеками. соответственно вместо $ надо писать jQuery, все будет работать.
Поменять там, где используете именно jQuery. т.е. в вашем скрине 1,2,4,5 подчеркнутые функции. там где у вас свои переменные типа $span менять не нужно.